# Add same file to multiple Team City artifacts

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to include the same file, `version.txt` in two separate zip files, created as artifacts in Team City. When the build runs, the `version.txt` file is only ever included in the last zip file. It is never added to any other zip file. Can anyone shed any light as to why this would happen?

At the moment, my artifact creation paths are as follows:

```
%ArtifactLocation%\ui\**\*.* => ui.zip!\lib\
%ArtifactLocation%\version.txt => ui.zip!\
...
%ArtifactLocation%\tools\**\*.* tools.zip!\lib\
%ArtifactLocation%\version.txt => tools.zip\
```

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you running?

Comment: TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.1 (build 37059)

Comment: hmmm.. that is what I'm using as well but it works just fine for me.

Comment: Could you try a different destination path? like:

`version.txt => ui.zip!\version\`
`verstion.txt => tools.zip!\version\`

just as a test.

Comment: Weirdly, that doesnt work either:  `%ArtifactLocation%\version.txt => ui.zip!\version\`

Comment: Most strange. I just created a quick test build to try the same and again it worked no problem.